# How to fix XMLbean Error in Apache Poi XSSF?

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-poi

I tried to use XSSF (.xlsx) in android

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildStreamToNodeMethod(XmlBeans.java:251)
...
...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif-4sjKuPiaYY6uCxQV1fSGmg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif-4sjKuPiaYY6uCxQV1fSGmg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif-4sjKuPiaYY6uCxQV1fSGmg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

it does not show an error when I use HSSF, but HSSF border has been deprecated, I need to use the border in my excel file

this example code I used

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
                CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
                Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue(1);

                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
                        createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);

                try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx")) {
                    wb.write(fileOut);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.d("SaveData Exception","Error"+e);
                }
```

Comment: Pretty sure HSSF hasn't deprecated borders entirely... Did you check the deprecation message to see what class enum you need to change to?

Comment: i just check this website [link] (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFBorderFormatting.html) and saw HSSF doesn't support table borders, so always BorderStyle.NONE

Comment: Do you know or have example code make border in apache poi 4.1.2?

Comment: The latest Apache POI 4.1.x docs are [here for HSSFBorderFormatting](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFBorderFormatting.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
XSSFWorkbook();
```

to

```
HSSFWorkbook();
```

This help for me.
Don't foget

```
 implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
 implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
```

Comment: getting this error:   Caused by: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two dependencies to the build.gradle module file

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'
```